# leaves of Areca Palm is drying after moving to a different flower pot

Tags: leaves, potting-soil, dryness

I had bought areca palm from a flower shop and kept it in the hall, it was flourishing all the while from past two months. Since, it was doing well, I thought of moving this plant into a bigger flower pot and also segregate them into different pots.

Kept the main stem intact and took other stems and planted into different flower pots, its been 3 days since then however the plants seem to show some distress and leaves are showing sign of dry leaves which wasn't the case earlier.

Important to note that, the types of soil in bought plant was of different quality than what I have used now. Earlier type was more of dry type and was full of wooden powder and coconut scrub type material whereas now I am using soil which is compost type.

Kindly advise on how to rejuvenate these plants and get them back to their flourishing state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're saying you split the plant's roots in order to pot up parts separately. Unless the palm was very large and broad across the base, with several strongly growing major stems, and you then carefully separated out the strong stems with strong root growth attached to each, this was not a good idea. Information here on whether and when to divide palms https://homeguides.sfgate.com/separate-palm-clump-98672.html. If you only just bought the plant in the last few months, it is unlikely it was large enough to divide in this way.

The smaller parts you potted up are unlikely to survive; if the main stem had a good root system attached and you did not damage it too much, that may recover. If it did not have good roots attached, or they were too damaged during the splitting process, it may not. There is nothing you can do to save the parts you split -just keep them watered as necessary, without keeping them waterlogged, and in suitable environmental conditions.

Comment: I grow palm trees from seeds.  The most dangerous is the potting up.  Just a little root damage can mean the end. I agree it is unlikely the small ones will survive.   Here is some advice I have I picked up from Junglemusic.net a big palm grower;   'Typically newly potted up palms need frequent misting to reestablish. Use of anti-transpirants or B vitamins may be useful'